# how to scroll element to view port

Tags: java, cucumber

Below code is used for initiate driver,

```
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "12");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "UIAutomator2");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.settings");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity",".Settings");


        String appuimURL = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/";
        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL(appuimURL), cap);
        SetUp.setDriver(driver);
```

I've tried various codes to scroll elements that don't appear in the view port but nothing works. one more information i am assigning this appiumdriver to WebElement in SetUp.setDriver() method.

Answer (score 0):

For Android:
driver.findElements(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text("Google"));"));

Comment: For clarity, it would help others if you could format your answer to include proper code blocks.